# Eclipse STS svn svn:ignore, not letting me ignore certain files

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnignore

I'm using Eclipse STS and SVN on Windows. I'm able to check-in/out from STS, no problem, but when I commit from STS I want to ignore generated files like .class, etc. So I'm trying to use the SVN Property tab and setting the property `svn:ignore` with the following exclusions...

```
target
target-eclipse
*.class
```

But when I commit from eclipse, the `.class` file still get displayed in the Commit dialog. Is the ignore pattern wrong? I tried using `/*.class` but eclipse won't let me save that pattern claiming the pattern is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These patterns only apply to the current folder.  As such, what you've provided will only exclude files or folders with those names from the root folder, but not any sub-folders.  I don't believe that there is a SVN option that allows for these patterns to apply to all sub-folders as well.

Shouldn't all of your *.class files be in your "target" folder, or another "bin" folder anyway - separated from the source files?  If / once so, then you can exclude that folder, which will exclude all of its children as well.

Alternatively, within Eclipse, under Window / Preferences / Team / Ignored Resources, you can add patterns there (e.g. `*.class`) - which will globally apply everywhere.  (But I'd highly recommend the above approach instead.)

Comment: Yes, all of my class files get generated under `target` and `target-eclipse` folders, but when I try to use `/target/**` or the `/` at all, eclipse complains and won't let me save the settings

Comment: @RaffiM - You don't need those.  `target` and `target-eclipse` are enough on their own, as long as everything else is within them.  I'd just make sure that those folders don't already exist in SVN, which could be confusing for a client.

Comment: You're right, I had the folders in svn not knowing they were there..I deleted them and now, from eclipse, when I commit I don't see any classes folders displayed in the commit dialog, thanks!